# How to stop VC# from redirecting console output to the output window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stdout

I have a GUI C# app that uses a console created with `AllocConsole`. It works under normal conditions, but when the app is started in debug mode under Visual Studio, all output ends up in the Visual Studio Output window. How do I stop that?

I am using C# 3.5 and Visual Studio Pro 2010.
The process hosting option is off.

Comment: No, that should work just fine if the C# code *actually* uses Console.Write/Line().  If it does something like Debug.Print or tracing then output is written by OutputDebugString() and ends up in a debugger window.  The Output window.  Consider SysInternals' DebugView utility.

Comment: I use Console.WriteLine and it ends up in the Visual Studio output window, instead of my console.

Comment: Hard to explain.  Try turning off the hosting process option.

Comment: Thanks for trying. The process hosting option is already off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My solution was to reset the standard streams to the newly created console myself. Here is the code:

```
public static class ConsoleHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allocates a console and resets the standard stream handles.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Alloc()
    {
        if (!AllocConsole())
            throw new Win32Exception();
        SetStdHandle(StdHandle.Output, GetConsoleStandardOutput());
        SetStdHandle(StdHandle.Input,  GetConsoleStandardInput());
    }

    private static IntPtr GetConsoleStandardInput()
    {
        var handle = CreateFile
            ( "CONIN$"
            , DesiredAccess.GenericRead | DesiredAccess.GenericWrite
            , FileShare.ReadWrite
            , IntPtr.Zero
            , FileMode.Open
            , FileAttributes.Normal
            , IntPtr.Zero
            );
        if (handle == InvalidHandleValue)
            throw new Win32Exception();
        return handle;
    }

    private static IntPtr GetConsoleStandardOutput()
    {
        var handle = CreateFile
            ( "CONOUT$"
            , DesiredAccess.GenericWrite | DesiredAccess.GenericWrite
            , FileShare.ReadWrite
            , IntPtr.Zero
            , FileMode.Open
            , FileAttributes.Normal
            , IntPtr.Zero
            );
        if (handle == InvalidHandleValue)
            throw new Win32Exception();
        return handle;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetStdHandle(StdHandle nStdHandle, IntPtr hHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateFile
        (                               string         lpFileName
        , [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] DesiredAccess  dwDesiredAccess
        , [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare      dwShareMode
        ,                               IntPtr         lpSecurityAttributes
        , [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode       dwCreationDisposition
        , [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAttributes dwFlagsAndAttributes
        ,                               IntPtr         hTemplateFile
        );

    [Flags]
    enum DesiredAccess : uint
    {
        GenericRead    = 0x80000000,
        GenericWrite   = 0x40000000,
        GenericExecute = 0x20000000,
        GenericAll     = 0x10000000
    }

    private enum StdHandle : int
    {
        Input  = -10,
        Output = -11,
        Error  = -12
    }

    private static readonly IntPtr InvalidHandleValue = new IntPtr(-1);
}
```

Comment: which namespace does `DesiredAccess` come from?

Comment: ah, seems like it is derived from http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createfile

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the output by launching the application differently like so <sup>(ref 1)</sup>:

```
//
// Setup the process with the ProcessStartInfo class.
//
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName = @"C:\MyExe.exe"; // Specify exe name.
start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

You can also consume the output (if desired) by the following <sup>(ref 1)</sup>:

```
//
// Start the process.
//
using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
{
    //
    // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
    //
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.Write(result);
    }
}
```

References:
(1) http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput

Comment: I am not redirecting another executable's streams.